# Xcode 10 and 11, no advanced syntax coloring (C++)

Tags: c++, xcode, syntax-highlighting

I have been using Xcode (10.3, on macOS 10.14) for C++ programming and have found that the syntax highlighting is *extremely* rudimentary. I am not able to get function parameters colored separately, nor operators, nor brackets.

Here is what I have been trying:

> - configuring the syntax coloring in Xcode->Preferences->Fonts and Colors (see pic below)
> - selecting C++ in Editor->Syntax Coloring (file type, language)
> - associating all .cpp files with "C++ source type"
> - associating all .cpp files with a specific compilation target
> - all project-level settings (eg. build settings) are set explicitly to C++

[image: really, there only exist these properties for syntax coloring??]

*...really, there only exist these properties for syntax coloring??*

> - also I installed Xcode 11 beta5 and still only rudimentary syntax coloring.

I have been searching for this for 2 full days (in fear of being flamed for asking an off-topic or just exceedingly silly question) but found no solution.

Some of the discussions I found led me to believe that there does exist a solution... consisting of "doing everything right" (as suggested by some, I tried deleting definition folders, didn't work, looked at .xccolortheme and DTDs PropertyList and found no suitable properties in either, installed additional color themes, etc.), others led me to believe that Xcode simply does not provide "advanced" syntax coloring like that of Eclipse, VS Code, etc.

I'm really confused because Xcode is used by a million (?) developers, surely it *must* have "advanced" syntax coloring, out of the box and fool-proof like many other IDEs. Can you please help me? A link to some for-dummies how-to will be more than welcome. Many thanks.

Comment: It's funny because I use Visual Studio and I tend to turn off most of these 'advanced features'. I learned programming when they weren't available and so I guess I don't need them. Plus they really annoy me when they get stuff wrong (which happens a lot in a language as complex as C++). Maybe we should swap?

Comment: @john, yeah i see what u mean. i actually only use about 5 different colors, eg. for operators, punctuation and brackets, function parameters. alas, all of these are considered (?) plain text by xcode. im sure i must be doing something wrong (although i havent done ...anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the only settings for Xcode. And as you can see they probably won't change it in Xcode 11.